# c# syntax shortcut to skip an object name when refering to it multiple times in a row

Tags: c#, syntax, shortcut

Was there any shortcut in c# that would allow to simplify this:

```
List<string> exampleList = new List<string>();
exampleList.Add("Is");
exampleList.Add("it");
exampleList.Add("possible");
```

and into something like this:

```
 var exampleList = new List<string>();
 exampleList {
.Add("is");
.Add("it");
.Add("possible");
}
```

I know it's possible to assign properties during declaration like this:

```
var myObject = new MyObject{
Id = "Useful",
Name = "Shortcut"
};
```

It would be interesting to know if there are other useful shortcuts like that, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static class ListExt
{
    public static List<T> Append<T>(this List<T> self, params T[] items)
    {
        if (items != null && self != null)
            self.AddRange(items);

        return self;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Append("Or", "you", "can", "use", "an", "extension", "method");

list.Append("Or").Append("like").Append("this");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var exampleList = new List<string>() {
    "Yes", "kinda", "with", "collection", "initializers" };
```

Note that you can also do this for multi-parameter Add methods, like dictionaries:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    {"abc", 124}, {"def",456}
};
```

Comment: Thx. But what about when an object is already initialized and you just want to refer to it multiple times and skip its name?

Comment: @CoolCodeBro then no. Just use the name multiple times. You could write a fluent extensions method api - but there really isn't any point